# Unzip file in Google Drive using colab?

Tags: google-drive, google-colab

I tried using the command:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive/')

!unzip -uq "/gdrive/My Drive/File.zip" -d "/gdrive/My Drive/File/"
```

This worked out for small file like a zipped image but for bigger files(2GB .MP4 zipped file) it gives this error: `bad zipfile offset`

Comment: Related [How to unzip a .zip file on Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/111664/88163). [How can I unzip multiple zip files?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126081/88163)

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab resources are dynamically limited. First check that your account has enough storage space available, then try again later.

If the problem persists...

from https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits

> Users with high computational needs may be interested in using Colab’s UI with a local runtime running on their own hardware. Users interested in having higher and more stable usage limits may be interested in [Colab Pro](http://colab.research.google.com/signup?utm_source=faq&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=what_are_usage_limits).

Comment: I have unlimited cloud storage so it could be resource-limits. Do you know any alternative to Colab Pro that could do the thing?

Comment: @AkshatNagar I'm sorry, I don't. I suggest you to post a question about that alternatives in [softwarerecs.se].